# Sqlalchemy keep object while using func.sum

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use the func.sum( function while still keeping the object as output for serialization with Marshmallow.

```
query = (
session.query(Employee, func.sum(JobEntry.number_registered).label('hours_on_project'))
.join(JobEntry, Employee.employee_hashkey==JobEntry.employee_hashkey)
.filter(JobEntry.job_number.like('1011811%'))
.group_by(Employee)
.order_by(sa.desc('hours_on_project'))
).first()
```

The query returns:

```
(<Employee object>, 8327.0)
```

I would like it to return the JobEntry object in addition to the sum:

```
(<Employee object>, <JobEntry object>, 8327.0)
```

Tried adding JobEntry in the query but then I get an OperationalError..

How do I add the JobEntry object as output while still using func.sum?

Comment: Which JobEntry would you want to get as output?

Comment: @IljaEverilä Ohh, I see the obvious problem... It's not a 1:1 but 1:many.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JobEntry table is not 1:1 with the Employee table.
If they where 1:1 the answer would be adding JobEntry to the query and group by like so:

```
query = (
session.query(Employee, JobEntry, func.sum(JobEntry.number_registered).label('hours_on_project'))
.join(JobEntry, Employee.employee_hashkey==JobEntry.employee_hashkey)
.filter(JobEntry.job_number.like('1011811%'))
.group_by(Employee, JobEntry)
.order_by(sa.desc('hours_on_project'))
```

)

Adding JobEntry to 1:M is possible, but would be wrong in my case..